# Is it possible to run a .net core app in docker with dotnet watch + debugging

Tags: docker, debugging, .net-core, watch

I want to have my docker container restart the process when a change is made in the source code.
I've found "dotnet watch --project ..." which works like a breeze to detect changes, but I can't debug using this in Rider.

I build the whole app and debugging works, but then it does not detect file changes.

It seems like dotnet watch is not compatible with debuggers. I've searched for 2 workdays. Can't find my answer.

If some logical simple answer exists to why this is not possible I'd love to know. It's almost like every author writing blog posts never seemed to need this functionality so they don't even talk about it.

```
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "AiaApi.dll"]
```

The above example shows a final stage of the dockerfile which enables me to use debugging but not reload after file change.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "watch", "--project", "Core", "run", "--urls=http://+:5000", "--configuration", "Debug"]
```

Above example shows the command to enable reload on file change, but has no debugging.

Comment: The reason it doesn't work is that you don't have the source code in the final image. The goal of the Dockerfile you have is to package the executable code into an image that's ready for deployment. It's not meant for interactive development. If you want to do that, you need a very different Dockerfile. And the Dockerfile you'd then have wouldn't be suitable for deployment.

Comment: Hmm not sure if you're analysing my dockerfile or explaining the whole situation to me. 

Every tutorial I've found shows me that, for debugging to work, you HAVE TO get the Dockerfile in a 'final' state. That's when debugging works, but I lose access to my source files since the whole things is packaged. 

I've not found a way to have debugging work while keeping access in the docker container to my code.

Ideal scenario is that debugging works, and it detects my local changes and starts auto rebuilding or re-debugging. If you know how to do it I'd love to know.